# Kinetic ROS package repository for Raspbian?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any plans to provide a Kinetic package repository for Raspbian? There are ROS ARM packages for Ubuntu and Debian, but nothing for Raspbian, which is virtually the same.

There are no stable images for Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi, so I've been forced to use Raspbian, but the only option to install ROS under Raspbian is by building from source, which is painfully slow, incredibly complicated, and error prone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238645/kinetic-ros-package-repository-for-raspbian?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried installing Kinetic for Raspian by building it from source. The compilation process succeeded after messing around and installing possible missing dependencies from source. But I reached a dead end after installation, when I tried to run a node besides roscore. I faced a "Segmentation Fault" error, though the node was very basic, and surely worked on a normal kinetic installation on Ubuntu. I still don't fully understand the reason behind this, but I think it might be related to the fact that Raspian is modified from a normal Debian Jessie distribution to fit the specific needs of The RPi

---

Originally posted by [Mahmoud Abdul Galil](https://answers.ros.org/users/23615/mahmoud-abdul-galil/) with karma: 106 on 2016-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0